# Regex replacing non-words chars in strings, ignoring specific chars

Tags: regex, vb.net, regex-negation

In VB.net I've got the following line that removes all non-alphanumeric chars from a string:

```
return Regex.Replace(build, "[\W]", "")
```

I now need to extend this to remove non-alphanumeric chars that aren't [] or _.

I've changed the line to:

```
return Regex.Replace(build, "[\W\[\]_]", "")
```

However I'm pretty sure that this says

> replace non-word or [ or ] or _

how do I negate the tests for the [] and _ chars so that it says

```
replace non-word and not [ and not ] and not _
```

Some examples:

```
"[Foo Bar_123456]" => "[FooBar_123456]"
"[Foo Bar_123-456*]" => "[FooBar_123456]"
```

(More can be supplied if necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [character set subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction):

```
[\W-[_\[\]]]
```

Ie. `\W` with `_`, `[` and `]` removed (latter two needing an escape because they are meta-characters in a character set). A verbatim string `@"..."` avoids needing to escape each backslash from C#:

```
var re = new Regex(@"[\W-[_\[\]]]");
```

Comment: I see. Should the pattern be: `[\W-[\_\[\]]]`?

Comment: @JonEgerton Oops, yes. Got carried away with backslashes :-).

Comment: `[\W-[][]]` works, too.  `]` doesn't have to be escaped if it's the first character after the opening `[` or `[^`; `[` isn't special if it doesn't follow `-`; and `_` is not matched by `\W`, so there was never any need to list it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
[^\w\[\]]
```

It says match (and then replace) everything except alphanumeric (including "_"), "[", and "]"